Lua Love2D, CS50's Introduction to Game Development, knife library Timer.tween syntax
I'm working through the CS50 intro to game dev course and I'm having a syntax error I've been beating my head against.
I'm trying to write a function using the knife timer library that will be called every update to check the current alpha to see if it is at it max or min value and if so tween it to the opposite to create a pulsing effect. However I'm getting a syntax error that I can't solve. I've looked at the examples from the lecture, the repo provided for the project, and the knife timer library readme and been unable to find how my syntax varies from any of them.
Function below
function Tile:shimmer()
    if self.alpha == SHINYHIGHESTALPHA then
        Timer.tween(1, {
        [self] = {self.alpha = SHINYLOWESTALPHA}
        })
    elseif self.alpha == SHINYLOWESTALPHA then
        Timer.tween(1, {
        [self] = {self.alpha = SHINYHIGHESTALPHA}
        })
    end
end

and the error I get, line 41 is [self] = {self.alpha = SHINYLOWESTALPHA}
Error

Syntax error: src/Tile.lua:41: '}' expected near '='



Traceback

[love "callbacks.lua"]:228: in function 'handler'
[C]: at 0x7ffeef872fa0
[C]: in function 'require'
src/Dependencies.lua:35: in main chunk
[C]: in function 'require'
main.lua:34: in main chunk
[C]: in function 'require'
[C]: in function 'xpcall'
[C]: in function 'xpcall'



Try this instead:
function Tile:shimmer()
    if self.alpha == SHINYHIGHESTALPHA then
        Timer.tween(1, {
        [self] = {alpha = SHINYLOWESTALPHA}
        })
    elseif self.alpha == SHINYLOWESTALPHA then
        Timer.tween(1, {
        [self] = {alpha = SHINYHIGHESTALPHA}
        })
    end
end

You're not supposed to put self. prefixes inside of table constructors.

Yes thankyou that worked. Looking at it now its kind of obvious that the self. was redundant.

@MatthewKlassen If my answer solved your problem, please accept it with the check mark.

using self. inside table constructors is fine as long as your syntax is ok.

{self.alpha = SHINYLOWESTALPHA} is invalid syntax
{ someKey = someValue } is syntactic sugar for { ["someKey"] = someValue} but this is only allowed for valid Lua identifiers which may not contain a dot.
Lua names may consist of numbers, letters and underscore and may not start with a number.
So depending on what you want to achieve you either need to use
{ ["self.alpha"] = SHINYLOWESTALPHA } to use "self.alpha" as your key (unlikely) or { ["alpha"] = SHINYLOWESTALPHA} or { alpha = SHINYLOWESTALPHA} to use "alpha" as your key
or if you actually want to use the value self.alpha as the key:
{ [self.alpha] = SHINYLOWESTALPHA }

